# creating a custom attribute to control rounding behavior

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, rounding

I have a class with a lot of Decimal properties that are used for financial calculations.  There are rules that specify how many decimal places to use when rounding each number.  There is no global rule - some are two decimal places, some 0, some 8, etc.

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to approach this.  I want to avoid having rounding logic spread all over the place in my code.  I know I can write a custom setter for each property that rounds the value when I assign it.

This seems like something I could do with a custom attribute.  However, I haven't written a custom attribute before, and I can't find a good example that does something similar to what I want, so I might be barking up the wrong tree.

Is this possible?  If so, what's a good example of how to approach this?

If not, are there any other methods I should consider other than the custom setter?

Comment: You can certainly slap an attribute on a property, but by itself it's just a piece of (meta)data; it doesn't actively "do" anything. So, what will be doing the rounding?

Comment: Good point.  I guess I would still need a custom setter, but maybe I could use an attribute to control the level of precision used by the rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/) or some other .NET-based AOP framework.  Here is the [MethodExecutionEventArgs.ReturnValue property](http://doc.postsharp.org/1.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp.HxS/ClassRef/html/a0fbc1ff-25a6-05f5-e1b6-4c1730f6c30b.htm) that says it can be used to "modify the return value..."

This will do it:

```
[Serializable]
public class RoundingAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        base.OnExit(eventArgs);
        eventArgs.ReturnValue = Math.Round((double)eventArgs.ReturnValue, 2);
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public double NotRounded { get; set; }

    public double Rounded { [Rounding] get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var c = new MyClass
                {
                    Rounded = 1.99999, 
                    NotRounded = 1.99999
                };

        Console.WriteLine("Rounded = {0}", c.Rounded); // Writes 2
        Console.WriteLine("Not Rounded = {0}", c.NotRounded);  // Writes 1.99999
    }
}
```